# HTML Javascript Camera capture

Tags: camera

I am designing an html field report where each section could have photo evidence inserted. I have used the several excellent examples of this

```html
 <input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" id="takePictureField">
```

and got a working example that works on my iPad and Android phone.
Question: I can only get one picture to show; how do I get multiple pictures captured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `multiple` attribute to the input field:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp

Comment: Thanks Alon. Sometimes the answer is staring you in the face and it just needs somebody else to point you in the right direction. Instead of adding photos to each section of the report I will just add a photo section at the end and the user can submit as many as they want.Thanks again.

Comment: But what does this actually do with a camera - I've placed this on https://methodfish.com/demo/javascript-camera/stills-camera-multiple.html to experiment via a mobile device but see no difference in this and one without (https://methodfish.com/demo/javascript-camera/stills-camera.html) .. or is it only for desktop (file selection) mode?